# Padding around ansible's blockinfile

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible's [`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) to add stuff to config files. But the result is really messy.

```
- blockinfile:
  dest: /foo/bar
  marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server"
  block: |
    A=true
    B=100
```

Result:

```
# other stuff
hello=goodbye
something=1
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server
A=true
B=100
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server
```

What I want:

```
# other stuff
hello=goodbye
something=1
                                                     # <--- blank line here
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server
A=true
B=100
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server
```

I'd like padding before/after the ansible block, otherwise the files become unreadable.

Is that possible?

(I tried a `\n` in the marker and marker's begin/end, but that destroys idempotency.)

Comment: It's not possible. *`blockinfile`* won't touch anything outside the block. Try add empty line by *`lineinfile`*, e.g. "insertbefore <BEGIN regex>", "insertafter <END regex>".

Comment: @VladimirBotka That's unfortunate. But thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done, currently, as one task.

But as @VladimirBotka mentioned in his comment, a workaround exists:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    dest: /foo/bar
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server"
    block: |
      A=true
      B=100

- ansible.builtin.replace:
    dest: /foo/bar
    regexp: "(?<!\n\n)(# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server)"
    replace: '\n\1'           # or '\n\1\n' for padding before and after
```

That also works when there are multiple blocks one after the other. (Detail of the regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76344787/9971404).)

But this is not ideal - it would be nice if `blockinfile` could handle the padding using a new option.

## I added a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/80835) to the repo. If you want this feature then please upvote that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be possible and work?

Have the original config file contain the following contents:

```
# other stuff
hello=goodbye
something=1

# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK configure server
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. The text is inserted by ansible as shown above, without empty line. That's the core of the problem - I need to put the newline in there myself as a separate task because the `blockinfile` module doesn't have an option to do so.