# Regex match line only if not preceded by empty line

Tags: regex

I need to match a line which is not preceded by an empty line, and prepend it with a newline.

So I want to transform this:

```
a = 1
b = 2

# header                    <--- do not match this
f = 10
g = 20
# header                    <--- match this
x = abc
y = def
```

To this:

```
a = 1
b = 2

# header
f = 10
g = 20

# header
x = abc
y = def
```

I tried `(?!\n)(# header)` with replacement `\n\1`, but that matches both lines: [regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/Rn8J86/1).

(I need this for ansible, so it's python regex.)

To satisfy the comments below, note that the "empty" line is really empty; it contains no whitespace.

Comment: You probably want a negative *lookbehind* for two newlines https://regex101.com/r/Rn8J86/2

Comment: Use `(?<!\n)\n(# header)` - https://regex101.com/r/3j6yE5/1

Comment: What language is this for?

Comment: This is the definition of 1 or more blank lines `\r\n\s*\r\n` Together with `^[#][ ]header` and given `(?m)` is what you have to move past. You could match both and use a callback to insert the proper blank line. It's ridiculous to believe only  two newlines represent a _`blank line`_  Can use this in a callback `(\r\n\s*\r\n^[#][ ]header)|(^[#][ ]header)`

https://regex101.com/r/EMBvz0/1

If group 1 matched, just write it back, else write back newline plus group 2.

Comment: `ridiculous to believe only two newlines represent a blank line1`  the word `only`. `\n \n` wont match `\n\n`, both are _blank_ lines. Blank lines are more _`visual`_. If you're not seeking a visual solution, no problem then.

Comment: @sln I added text to the end of the question, to address your critique. Thanks.

Comment: You said _`Blank`_ originally, maybe you should change that to _`Empty`_ as well so there is no confusion. Just realize the definition of _blank lines_ in regexland is `\n\s*\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which language you're looking to target, but here would be an example in Javascript using [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
let original = 
`a = 1
b = 2

# header
f = 10
g = 20
# header
x = abc
y = def`;

let replaced = original.replace(/(?<!\n\n)(# header)/, '\n$1');
console.log(replaced);
```

Or in python from [Codepen](https://codepen.io/harunpehlivan/full/qBNpGKr):

```py
import re
s='''a = 1
b = 2

# header
f = 10
g = 20
# header
x = abc
y = def'''
x = re.sub(r'(?<!\n\n)(# header)', r'\n\1', s)
print(x)
```

Comment: It's for python, but no matter because your js regex worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @lonix sure updated for python too.

Comment: It may not be a problem, but if the line were `"a few words before # header"` a newline character would be inserted before `"# header"`. Also, if the first line were `# header"` a blank line would be inserted before it. I don't know if that is wanted.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yea good point. Maybe an easier solution would just be to normalize the entire document so there are no successive newlines. And then add an additional newline before every "header" however it is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace (zero-width) matches of

```
(?<=(?<!\n)\n)(?=# header$)
```

with `"\n"`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5wvUNF/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=         # begin positive lookbehind
  (?<!       # begin negative lookbehind
    \n       # match literal
  )          # end negative lookbehind
  \n         # match literal
)            # end positive lookbehind
(?=          # begin positive lookahead
  # header   # match literal
  $          # match end of string
)            # end positive lookahead
```

Note that the positive lookbehind

```
(?<=(?<!\n)\n)
```

has the same effect as (and could be replaced with )

```
(?<=\n)(?<!\n\n)
```

Comment: Thanks this is an important catch. As you explained in a comment above, "if the line were `a few words then # header` a newline would be inserted before `# header`".

Comment: `\#[ ]header` since this is formatted in the breakdown.

Comment: Also nice use of a compound assertion. Or can't I say that ?

Comment: @sin, of course you can say that, it's music to my ears.